# Reading array of objects in angular

Tags: angular

I have a  code that returns objects below after calling an API:

```
{"status":"success","data":[{"id":"1","employee_name":"Tiger 
Nixon","employee_salary":"320800","employee_age":"61","profile_image":""}, 
{"id":"2","employee_name":"Garrett 
Winters","employee_salary":"170750","employee_age":"63","profile_image":""}, 
{"id":"3","employee_name":"Ashton 
Cox","employee_salary":"86000","employee_age":"66","profile_image":""}
```

This is the code block that retrieves the data:

```
myEmployees: Employee[];

getEmployees() {
this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
.subscribe((response) => {
this.myEmployees = response;
console.log(this.myEmployees); 
});
}
```

I have also created a class Employee as below:

```
export class Employee {
id: any;
employee_name: any;
employee_salary: any;
employee_age: any;
profile_image: any;
}
```

I want to store the results retrieved in an array of type Employee and then display an alert for each employee in the array. I am not very familiar with typescript, I tried the below but does not seem to work. I cannot access the properties of Employees. Anyone know how this can be achieved?

```
for (let m of this.myEmployees) {
alert(m.employee_name);
}
```

Comment: When is the for loop called?

Comment: Hi, it is called in another function when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Hello you have to iterate

> this.myEmployees.data

something like

```
this.myEmployees.data.forEach(employee => {
console.log(employee)
});
```

Reason: The data is present inside the **data** array.

On side note do this, it'll work fine

```
getEmployees() {
this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
.subscribe((response) => {
this.myEmployees = response.data;
console.log(this.myEmployees); 
});
```

}

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, it says that property .data does not exist.

Comment: hello, when you assign this  `this.myEmployees = response.data;`. you can directly iterate the value like this `this.myEmployees.forEach(employee => {
console.log(employee)
});`

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not allow .data to be assigned to response.

Comment: try this `getEmployees() {
this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
.subscribe((response : any) => {
this.myEmployees = response.data;
this.myEmployees.forEach(employee => { console.log(employee) });
});
}`

Answer (score 1):

first your JSON is not valid
the valid JSON would be

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "employee_name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "employee_salary": "320800",
      "employee_age": "61",
      "profile_image": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "employee_name": "Garrett Winters",
      "employee_salary": "170750",
      "employee_age": "63",
      "profile_image": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "employee_name": "Ashton Cox",
      "employee_salary": "86000",
      "employee_age": "66",
      "profile_image": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

please do the following

edit get request

```
this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
.subscribe((response) => {
if(response && response['data']){
 this.myEmployees = response['data'];
 // because employee list is inside data property
 console.log(this.myEmployees); 
}
});
```

now you should be able to access you data

```
for (let m of this.myEmployees) {
  alert(m.employee_name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than subscribing to your data in the function, return the observable.

You can then subscribe to that, and iterate through it, or call as function as required.

**In your ts file**

```
myEmployees: Employee[] = [];

constructor() { 
   this.getEmployees().subscribe((data: Employee[]) => {
   this.myEmployees = data;
   this.alertFunction();
  }
}

getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.http.get<Employee[]>('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'); 
}

alertFunction() { // I assume this function is for testing, but using the console is far better so please remove this
   for (let employee of this.myEmployees) {
      alert(employee['employee_name']);
   }
}
```